# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck in power saver mode

Tags: power-management

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I noticed that I cannot toggle out of Power Saver mode. When I choose either Performance or Balanced, it immediately switches back to Power Saver.

I've tried using `powerprofilesctl set balanced` to manually set it and it seems to work fine (no error messages), but it doesn't seem to change anything as `powerprofilesctl list` still says it's in the `power-saver` profile.

I've also tried updating the kernel to the latest mainline (6.5.7-060507-generic) for other reasons, but this did not seem to affect the power settings.

Lastly, I've tried disabling the various power saving settings one-by-one in the BIOS but that had no effect.

I am currently running on a Lenovo Thinkpad P14s Gen 4 with an AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 7840U, plugged into a USB4 dock.

How can I ensure that my CPU is not being throttled? Should I be using tlp over powerdaemon (if so, is there a guide for this?)?

---

Update: I upgraded to 23.10 and it seemingly worked fine. But after some time, it reverted to the problematic behavior and I cannot figure out why yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue with the same laptop and Ubuntu 23.10. According to this article (https://www.phoronix.com/review/thinkpad-p14s-gen4), it's a BIOS issue. There seems to be an update to 1.13 available (mine is running 1.11).
Not sure if that already fixes the problem though.

Comment: I've updated to the latest kernel (6.5.0-14-generic) and BIOS (1.16?) and this seems to have resolved my issues. :)